# Compacting in Uniform Integration

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

If I have that $f$ is integrable, how show that 
for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $h>0$ for which we have that
$$\int_{\{x\in X \colon |f(x)|<h\}} |f(x)|d m<\varepsilon$$  in a general measure space.

And how we can obtain such $h>0$ if a sequence $(f_{n})$ of integrable functions is such that $|f_{n}|<g$ almost everywhere and $g$ is integrable, with the objective to obtain that for all $n$,  $$\int_{\{x\in X \colon |f_{n}(x)|<h\}} |f_{n}(x)|dm<\varepsilon?$$

Comment: these are two different problems

Comment: In the first question, if $h$ works for each $\varepsilon$ then the integral over $\{|f(x)|\lt h\}$ is $0$, which is not true in general. I guess the $h$ should work for a fixed $\varepsilon$ (and the parameter $n$ is irrelevant).

Comment: Yes, the h need to work for a fixed $\epsilon>0$

Answer (score 0):

1. First, find a set $A$ of finite measure such that $\int_A|f|\mathrm dm<\varepsilon/2$. Then $$\int_{\{|f|\lt h\}}|f|\mathrm dm\leqslant 
   \varepsilon/2+m(A)\cdot h.$$
2. This time, we take the set $A$ such that $\int_A|g|\mathrm dm<\varepsilon/2$.